# Add all items to a specific condition in loop

Tags: php

When $date matches criteria I want all games for $date displayed under heading today, however at the moment my code is looping and making a new heading for each criteria where $date = today as you can see in image. **There should only be one heading, for today** and then skip on to next day etc

[image]

```
while($row>$played){
            if($row['event_date']== $date){
            echo'<td>TODAY,'.$date.'</td>';
            :
            :
             }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` once and record the fact:

```
$echoed = false;

while($row>$played){   // not sure what this is doing $row is an array
    if($row['event_date'] == $date && !$echoed){
        echo $echoed = '<td>TODAY,'.$date.'</td>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping a variable that tracks the last date, then when last date is different that the date in the record, print a new header...

```
$lastdate = "";
while($row>$played){
  if($row['event_date']== $date){
    if ($lastdate != $date) {
      echo'<td>TODAY,'.$date.'</td>';
      $lastdate = $date;
    } 
    : #<- display match details here
    :
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data is not ordered or sorted, a suggestion is to store results in an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in php ie. key => array

Example:

```
$games = array();
while ($row > $played) {

    // for readability, named as date
    $date = $row['event_date'];

    // initialise as a new entry, if it hasnt already
    if (!isset($games[$date]) {
      $games[$date] = array();
    }

    // append data to array 
    $games[$date][] = ... // data added here
}
```

This will produce a data structure such as;

```
Array 
   2015-04-01 => [ delhi, crusaders ],
   2015-04-04 => [ a, c, d, b ],
   .
   .
```

Which you can easily output or format using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). 
Hope this helps.